# Только начал изучать ООП. В этом примере не могу понять почему деструктор первого обьекта не срабатывает, a второго срабатывает

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Myclass
{
private:

    int size;
public:
    int* data;
    Myclass(int size)
    {
        cout << "Вызван конструктор  " << this << endl << endl;
        this->size = size;
        this->data = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        {
            data[i] = i;

        }


    }
    Myclass(const Myclass& other)
    {
        this->size = other.size;
        this->data = new int[other.size];
        for (int i = 0; i <= other.size; i++)
        {
            this->data[i] = other.data[i];
        }

        cout << "Вызван конструктор копирования" << this << endl;
    }
    ~Myclass()
    {
        cout << "Вызван деструктор   " << this << endl;
        delete[] data;
    };
};





int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    Myclass A(5);
    Myclass B(A);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/fwyPyo - два конструктора, два деструктора...

Comment: Единственно тут выход за пределы массива `for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)` приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: @Harry Извиняюсь. Я запускаю в Visual studio неправильно работает. Скопировал этот код в онлайн компилятор - все работает правильно. Еще раз Sorry :)

Comment: @user7860670 Переделал на for (int i = 0; i < size; i++); стало работать правильно. Не подскажете почему именно?

Comment: Переполнение буфера потому что. Повреждение памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так лучше:

```
class Myclass
{
private:

    const size_t size;
public:
    int* data;
    //константные члены инициализируются в инициализаторе конструктора
    Myclass(const size_t size) : size(size)
    {
        cout << "Вызван конструктор  " << this << endl << endl;             
        data = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            data[i] = i;

        }
    }
    Myclass(const Myclass& other) : size(other.size)
    {            
        data = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            data[i] = other.data[i];
        }

        cout << "Вызван конструктор копирования " << this << endl;
    }
    ~Myclass()
    {
        cout << "Вызван деструктор   " << this << endl;
        delete[] data;
    };
};
```

Вы написали цикл, который пытается записывать  за пределы имеющегося массива, когда `i == size`. Это является причиной неопределенного поведения, а если есть неопределенное поведение, то результат неизвестен. Поэтому когда вы исправили на `i < size` поведение программы стало адекватным. 
И, в качеестве замечаний:

1. Если в классе храните размер массива, то всегда объявите его
   константным или константным выражением, и если функция не
   модифицирует свой аргумент, то его тоже сделайте константным, чтобы
   сразу стало понятно и чтобы случайно его не модифицировали, тем
   самым получая неожидаемый результат.
2. Не нужно выполнять лишный труд и искусственно сделать код менее
   читабельным, каждый раз делая явным указатель  `this`: экземпляры
   класса неявно имеют этот указатель, и (для неквалифицированных имен)
   `size` и  `this->size`  являются равнозначными выражениями.
3. Для `64_битных` приложений `int i` занимает `4` байта, а при
   операции `i++`  или при другой арифметической операции, он может
   увеличиться в пределах 4_х байтов, но размер массива в таком
   приложении может иметь значение в пределах `8_байт`(4 байта останутся неиспользованными), и тем самым ваш
   код становится не переносимым. Так что размер массива должен иметь 
   тип `size_t или ptrdiff_t`, которые в 4_х байтовых приложениях имеют
   размер 4 байта, а в 8_байтовых - 8 байт.
4. Вы уже инициализировали: `size = other.size;` так что дальше в коде
   вы можете использовать не **other.size** а **size**, опять же для
   читабельности (и меньше нажимать на кнопочки придется).
   Вот, кажется, я все рассказал о том, что я изменил в вашем коде. Ну и напоследок: имя закрытого члена обозначте таким именем,  чтобы потом не путать с именами аргументов. Например **sz** или **_size** и т.д...